# Can't save a PIL image file after cropping out extra transparent pixels

Tags: python, tuples, python-imaging-library, attributeerror, opencv

I have this function that takes svg logos, converts them to png (first for loop), removes the extra redundant transparent pixels and saves it to its destination folder (second for loop).

```
def convert_to_png(source_path, destination_path, output_w, output_h):
    if not os.path.exists(destination_path):
        os.mkdir(destination_path)

    # Turns SVG images to to PNG
    for i in os.listdir(source_path):
        new_file_name = i.split('.')
        new_file_name = new_file_name[0]
        cairosvg.svg2png(url=source_path + str(i), write_to=destination_path + str(new_file_name) + '.png',
                         output_width=output_w, output_height=output_h)

    for j in os.listdir(destination_path):

        img = cv2.imread(destination_path + j, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
        img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGRA2RGBA)

        logo = Image.fromarray(np.uint8(img)).convert('RGBA').crop().getbbox()

        logo.save(destination_path + j, 'PNG')
```

This is how I call the function:

```
convert_to_png(current_dir + '/riot_sponsors/', current_dir + '/new_logos/', 2000, 1500)
```

For some reason, I am getting this error:

```
logo.save(destination_path + j, 'PNG')
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'save'
```

My goal is to save the new cropped out png files to the `destination_path`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`.getbbox()`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/4.1.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.getbbox) returns a tuple of the left, right, upper, and lower coordinates. This is what is returned to the logo variable.

If you want to remove transparent portions of the image, use the following code:

```
logo = Image.fromarray(np.uint8(img)).convert('RGBA')
logo = logo.crop(logo.getbbox())
```

Comment: Yea but I still need to remove the extra transparent pixels

Comment: You can save that as a separate variable if you just want the bounding box. Like this: `logo_bbox = logo.getbbox()`

Comment: I want to take the png, crop out its extra transparent pixels and save it

Comment: @oo92 Oh, I see, you need to pass bbox into crop, let me update my answer